# Fetch Email of multiple entities using DNs in a single query

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I have DNs of 2 or more entities of my Ldap Server and need to fetch the email ids for them. Is there a way to do this in a single query. I looked at 'Extensible Match Search Filter) but couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `|` OR operator to construct your query filter:

```
(|(distinguishedName=<DN 1 goes here>)(distinguishedName=<DN 2 goes here>))
```

You can add more clauses if necessary, as long as the resulting filter string is less than 10MB in size (~5 million characters)

Comment: Thanks Mathias. This works. I was using dn in the query instead of distinguisedName and that wasn't working.

Comment: Hey Mathias, I have a follow up query. do you know if distinguishedName attribute is indexed. I am asking this because I am planning to run this query for 100 distinguished name at a time which might slow down if this field is not indexed. Thanks for your help.