# LDAP Query not possible / Workaround?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I am looking for a solution for the following problem.

I need to request Users of multiple Groups (over 200 Groups) out of an Active Directory.

Since it is not allowed to have Wildcard in the request
for example:  (memberOf=cn=T*,ou=Gruppen, ou=Test Users, dc=Test,dc=local)
i need a workaround.

Someone got an Idea?
I looked up several solutions, but no one worked out so far.
Is their maybe some form of "PlugIn" which would allow such a Wildcard?
Thought about a PowerShell Script which takes all users from the groups and put it in one huge group, which i could request than. Would something like this be possible?

Sadly I'm not realy experienced with LDAP querys.

Thanks in Advance!

Greeting,
Tobi

Comment: Use the `|` operator: `(|(memberOf=<group1 dn>)(memberOf=<group2 dn>)(...))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch Email of multiple entities using DNs in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68117490/fetch-email-of-multiple-entities-using-dns-in-a-single-query)

Comment: Try requesting the members of the groups ? searchbase : `ou=Gruppen, ou=Test Users, dc=Test,dc=local` and filter : `cn=T*` . You will have to sort the uniqueness of the members on client side though